# use umbraco as ftp server

Tags: ftp, umbraco

I have a site running using umbraco 4.7.1

The customer wants to create a client-only functionality where the user can upload various files (much like a ftp server) but to their own area within umbraco so each client's files are kept separate.

I am pretty new to Umbraco. How should I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FTP Functionality is not specific to Umbraco or any CMS for that matter. It is configurable in the IIS Server. It could be either the same server where you are running your Umbraco or a different one.

I'm also not much aware about the Umbraco CMS, but most CMS do provide you a way to extend their functionality in the form of plugins/modules. You may write your own Umbraco plugin that does the FTP transfer based on your requirement.

Here is a guide about how to write this FTP client in VB.NET programming language:

http://dot-net-talk.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-create-ftp-client-in-vbnet.html